# Is there a continous function which does not have a derivative in any of its points?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Continuous Functions Always Differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/are-continuous-functions-always-differentiable)

Is there a continous function (continous in every one of its points) which is not differentiable in any of its points?

Comment: Yes. The standard example is the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: Or a [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Brownian_scaling) - note the "fractal" nature of the image.

Comment: Yes, most (in the sense of category) continuous functions are nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you elaborate?

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136445/holder-continuous-but-not-differentiable-function/136500) might help

Comment: @Andris: Look at the continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to the reals, under the sup norm. Then the set of such functions that are continuous *somewhere* is meager. Standard result, I think it is in Oxtoby, but it should not be hard to track down a proof on the Web.

Comment: @André: your second "continuous" should be a "differentiable".

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks, yes, differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example the [Weierstraß function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

One can actually show that the set $A:= \{f \in C[0,1]; f$ has no right-derivative in any point in $[0,1)\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ and uncountable.

Comment: You can do even better: $A$ is co-meagre in $C[0,1]$.