# Rectifiability of Hölder Continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If a curve is Lipschitz continuous, it is rectifiable. What can be said about Hölder Continuous ones? Are they rectifiable too? Is there either proof or else an example of a function that is Holder continuous but not rectifiable?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion then $t \longmapsto B_t$ is almost surely Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha < \frac12$ and almost surely has infinite first variation. This gives a counterexample to Holder continuity implying rectifiability.

A proof is given here: http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/fall06/fall06.1.pdf or a quick google for "brownian motion holder continuity" gives many other proofs.

I don't know of an elementary example off the top of my head though.

You may want to look at [Hölder continuous but not differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136445/holder-continuous-but-not-differentiable-function) though. This example seems like it should have infinite first variation as well, but again I don't see an elementary proof.

Comment: Just as an extra: Rectifiability can be generalized to so called bounded $p$-variation: just replace the absolute values with absolute values to the power $p$. Functions of bounded $p$-variation and Hölder continuous functions are intimately related: A function has bounded $p$-variation if and only if it can be written as a reparametrization of a $1/p$-Hölder continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

The function

$$f(x) \; = \; x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

with $f(0) = 0$ is Hölder continuous with Hölder exponent $\frac{1}{2}$ (but not of any higher Hölder exponent). Two proofs can be found in: *Solution to Monthly Problem 3939*, **American Mathematical Monthly** 48 #6 (June-July 1941), 413-414 (doi:[10.2307/2302655](https://doi.org/10.2307/2302655)). As for proving $f(x)$ is not rectificable, you can use the same method that is used in the Math StackExchange question [Curve In a Closed Interval with an Infinite Length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137725/curve-in-a-closed-interval-with-an-infinite-length/137743#137743).