# Integer polynomial on integer values: dense mod $\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

I was trying to answer the question at [How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n^2)$ does not exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846791/how-to-show-that-this-limit-does-not-exists)

I was able to show that $\sin(n^2)$ does not tend to a limit, but am still unable to show that $n^2$ itself is dense mod $\pi$. Can this be deduced in a straightforward way from the famous theorem that the integers are dense mod $\pi$?

Also, are all integer polynomials dense modulus an irrational number? I struggle to find the relevant literature online.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality

Comment: expanding slightly on @JackD'Aurizio's answer: Let $f(x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial with integer coefficients. Weyl's inequality, applied to the sequence $\{f(n)/\pi\}$, shows that the sequence satisfies [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl.27s_criterion) and is therefore equidistributed modulo 1. This is even a bit stronger than saying $\{f(n)\}$ is dense modulo $\pi$.

Comment: so elementary methods aren't applicable?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I think so. Answering loosely: say we want an integer $n$ so that $n^2$ is "close to" a certain value $r$ mod $\pi$. Let $s = \sqrt{r}$. Because the integers are dense mod $\pi$, there is an integer $k$ so that $k$ is "close to" $s$. Let $n = k$. $n^2 \mathrm{mod} \pi = k^2 \mathrm{mod} \pi = (k \mathrm{mod} \pi)^2$. So $n^2$ is "close to" $s^2 = r$ mod $\pi$.

Comment: This doesn't work; just because $a$ and $b$ are close mod $\pi$ does not mean that $a^2$ and $b^2$ are close mod $\pi$.

Comment: No, you're right; on reflection, I was thinking too much in terms of integer modular arithmetic. Thanks for pointing that out.