# Series Convergence Criterion

Tags: convergence-divergence

The greatest value of *p* such that the series

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot \tan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^p}}\right) \cdot \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2 p}}\right)
\end{equation}

converges conditionally, what is the value of *p*?

Comment: Probably for: `p>=0` series is converges.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: If `p==0`, Then the series diverges.

Comment: @user64494 ,Yes for `p=0` is `Sum[(-1)^n Log[2] Tan[1], {n, 1, Infinity}]` then the series diverges.

Comment: I think you are looking for the least value of $p.$

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $$ \tan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^p}}\right) \cdot \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2 p}}\right)$$ is decreasing and convergent to $0$ for $p>0. $ Therefore the series is convergent due to the Leibniz test. The series is absolutely convergent for $p/2  + 2p>1$ as
$$\tan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^p}}\right) \cdot \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2 p}}\right )\approx n^{-p/2-2p}$$

For $p<0$ the general term does not tend to $0,$ as the $\log $ factor tends to $+\infty$ and $\sin(n^{-p/2})$ is dense in $[-1,1].$ This a nontrivial fact discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846791/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sinn2-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proof of the convergence of the series under consideration for `p > 0`.The simple-minded approach fails.

```
SumConvergence[(-1)^n*Tan[1/Sqrt[n^p]]*Log[1 + 1/n^(2*p)], n, 
Assumptions -> p > 0]
```

returns the input. In order to apply [the alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) we find

```
Asymptotic[Tan[1/Sqrt[n^p]]*Log[1 + 1/n^(2*p)], n -> Infinity
 , Assumptions -> p > 0]
```

> `n^(-5 p/2)`

Therefore, this tends to zero as `n` approaches infinity. Now we find

```
D[Tan[1/Sqrt[n^p]]*Log[1 + 1/n^(2*p)], n]
```

> `-((n^(-1 + p) p Log[1 + n^(-2 p)] Sec[1/Sqrt[n^p]]^2)/( 2 (n^p)^(3/2))) - (2 n^(-1 - 2 p) p Tan[1/Sqrt[n^p]])/(1 + n^(-2 p))`

It's clear that both terms are negative for `n>=1&&p>0` and

```
NMaximize[{-((n^(-1 + p) p Log[1 + n^(-2 p)] Sec[1/Sqrt[n^p]]^2)/(
2 (n^p)^(3/2))) - (2 n^(-1 - 2 p) p Tan[1/Sqrt[n^p]])/( 1 + n^(-2 p)),   n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && p > 0}, {n, p}
```

> `{-7.51567*10^-246, {n -> 28, p -> 67.9428}}`

confirms it. Now we can conclude the convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Applying Taylor's theorem to $\tan(x)$ and $\ln(1 + x)$ for $x$ around zero tells us that
$$\tan(1/\sqrt{n^p})\ln(1 + 1/n^{2p}) \sim \frac{1}{n^{p/2 + 2p}} = n^{-5p/2}.$$
The limit comparison test applied to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-5p/2}$ tells us that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \tan(1/\sqrt{n^p})\ln(1 + n^{-2p})$ is absolutely convergent for $p > 2/5$. Since $\tan(x)$ and $\ln(1+x)$ are monotonic functions, the alternating series test applied to this series implies that for $p > 0$, our series is conditionally convergent.

The answer is $p = 2/5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all there is another way to solve this question

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\tan \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{{{n}^{p}}}} \right)\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{{{n}^{2p}}} \right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{{{n}^{p}}}}\frac{1}{{{n}^{2p}}}}=1\\$$

Since the ratio 1 > 0, the two series have the same convergence properties.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^p} } \frac{1}{n^{2p}} =\frac{1}{n^{\frac{p}{2}+2p }} $$

Let

$$\frac{p}{2}+2p\le  1 \Rightarrow  p\le\frac{2}{5} $$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).