# Hölder continuity of Weierstrass Function

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Let us fix some notations, we will call Weierstrass function a function such that:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a^{n}\cos(b^{n}x) $$ 
with $0<a<1, b>1 \text{and} \ ab>1$.

Wondering whether a function of this type is Hölder continuous or not, I came up with [a wikipedia statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) claiming that such a function is Hölder continuous with exponent $-\log_{b}a$. After trying to prove that using some Prostaphaeresis formulas and giving a good estimate of the tail, I found a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136445/h%C3%B6lder-continuous-but-not-differentiable-function) on this forum. The argument used its pretty basic, but there are some problems, from now on I will use the notation used in the second answer of the previous link.

The choice of $m$ is not right, this can be seen using $b=3$ and $h=10$, a good constraint is $b^{m-1} |h| < 1 < b^{m} |h|$ this leads us to the inequality $b^{m}|h| < b$ instead of having $2$ on the right and side, but that's not the problem.

The main problem is the inequality $a^{m} < |h|^{-\log_{b}a}$, in fact from $ab>1$ follows that $ab^{m}>1$ and $m>-\log_{b}a$, moreover $ab^{m-1}>ab>1>b^{m-1}|h|$ so that $a>|h|$ and I'm not able from this to deduce if the inequality $a^{m} < |h|^{-\log_{b}a}$ holds true or not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another way to approach this is to use the Littlewood-Paley characterization of Holder spaces.

Comment: @Jose27 I don't know that characterization, any references?

Comment: Grafakos's "Modern Fourier Analysis" has this and is pretty accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does hold. Note that it suffices to show that 
$$m\log_ba<(-\log_ba)(\log_b|h|),$$ 
that is, $m>\log_b(1/|h|)$. This, however, is a direct consequence of the inequality $b^m|h|>1$, which holds, as you noted above.